# npm install ember-data just installs index.js file

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-data

When I do `npm install ember-data --save`, I get only the following files:

```
    ./node_modules/ember-data/
    ./node_modules/ember-data//lib
    ./node_modules/ember-data//lib/ember-addon
    ./node_modules/ember-data//lib/ember-addon/blueprints
    ./node_modules/ember-data//lib/ember-addon/blueprints/ember-data
    ./node_modules/ember-data//lib/ember-addon/blueprints/ember-data/index.js
    ./node_modules/ember-data//lib/ember-addon/index.js
    ./node_modules/ember-data//package.json
    ./node_modules/ember-data//README.md
```

I was expecting the same files bower installs, such as `ember-data.min.js`.

My hunch is I need to do `npm install` from within `node_modules/ember-data`? If so, why the extra step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ember-data` is meant to be installed with bower with

`$ bower install --save ember-data`

Installing `ember-data` with npm will add it as an add-on for `ember-cli` project. It will include the files from `bower_components`. you still need the bower version.

[ember-cli](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli) has built-in support for `ember-data`.

Comment: Is it OK to use two package managers or should I just use bower?

Comment: Bower is for front end dependencies, npm is for backend. Sometimes it mixes up, but generally you would use both.

Comment: how do I include the files installed using npm in ember-js. I have this requirement, to use ember-rickshaw,  it can not be installed using  bower, since its package is not available, but can be installed using npm, doing so the application does not recognize the constant Rickshaw.Graph.Ember. Please help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953049/how-to-get-reference-of-rickshaw-with-ember-cli-using-ember-rickshaw